# Dynamic title in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this `<i>` tag

```
 <i class="actionicon icon-star" [ngClass]="{'yellow' : data.isLiked}" (click)="Like(data)"
 aria-hidden="true" title="Liked"></i>
```

I have this `data.isLiked` is true then yellow class is added but i want to change the title also

if isLiked true then title should be `Unlike` otherwise `Like`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by binding your title attribute to angular, like this:`[title]=" data.isLiked ? 'Liked' : 'Unliked' "`

Example:

```
<i class="actionicon icon-star" [ngClass]="{'yellow' : data.isLiked}" (click)="Like(data)"
 aria-hidden="true" [title]=" data.isLiked ? 'Liked' : 'Unliked' "></i>
```